# How to target a letter after a dash in Javascript replace using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

What I have here is a script that changes the value in a textarea via onclick of a button. I do this using Javascript replace together with RegEx. So there's a specified value for every number.

In this sample, however, I couldn't make a **letter after a dash** to work.

```js
const mapper = new Map();
mapper.set("10th", "11th");
mapper.set("-", "Deleted");

mapper.set("63-51", "40");
mapper.set("121AA", "95");
mapper.set("121-I", "Deleted");
mapper.set("121-OO", "Deleted");

function fixtext() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  if (elm) {
    elm.value = elm.value
      .replace(
        /\b\d+(?:[A-Z]|([A-Z])\1|d|th|st|nd)?(|\-\d+)?\b/g,
        m => mapper.has(m) ? mapper.get(m) : m
      );
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50">121AA will become 95 and 63-51 will become 40. This should be the same for 121-I and 121-OO.</textarea>

<button class="nbtngreen" onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```

So after a click of the button, `121-I` should become `Deleted` as specified. That's also the case for `121-OO`.

I'd appreciate any help on how to fix the RegEx I'm using. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you also need to match `-`? Try `/\b\d+(?:-?([A-Z])\1?|[rn]d|th|st)?(?:-\d+)?\b|-/i`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tVsjT0/1).

Comment: `\-\d+` only matches numbers after `-`, not letters.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to escape `-` except inside `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp only matches `\d+` after `-`. Change that to `[A-Z\d]+` to match letters or digits there.

You don't need an alternative with an empty string inside a group with a `?` quantifier, since the quantifier means the other pattern is optional.

`[A-Z]|([A-Z])\1` can be simplified to just `([A-Z])\1?`.

```js
const mapper = new Map();
mapper.set("10th", "11th");
mapper.set("-", "Deleted");

mapper.set("63-51", "40");
mapper.set("121AA", "95");
mapper.set("121-I", "Deleted");
mapper.set("121-OO", "Deleted");

function fixtext() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  if (elm) {
    elm.value = elm.value
      .replace(
        /\b\d+(?:([A-Z])\1?|d|th|st|nd)?(-[A-Z\d]+)?\b/g,
        m => mapper.has(m) ? mapper.get(m) : m
      );
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50">121AA will become 95 and 63-51 will become 40. This should be the same for 121-I and 121-OO.</textarea>

<button class="nbtngreen" onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```